# Move every file that ends with 3 letter extension, but the last letter is either "g" of "f"?

Tags: mv

```
mv public_html/*.??[g,f] public_html/images/
```

Could that work? So that all photos/images that have the extensions .jpg, .png, and .gif will be moved.

(I don't have Linux installed and I used an online terminal. Unfortunately, they don't have any photos in their files)

Answer (score 5):

`[g,f]` matches on either `g`, `,` (comma) or `f`. You'd need `[fg]` for only `f` or `g`.

Now, technically.

```
mv public_html/*.??[gf] public_html/images/
```

Would also move a file called `foo.x.f` as `?` also matches a `.`.

Also, if there was no file matching that pattern, then some shells like `bash` could move a file called literally `*.??[gf]` ([a bug introduced by the Bourne shell, fixed again in `zsh`](/a/204944), you can work around it in `bash` with `shopt -s failglob`).

So, here for a 3 character extension that ends in `f` or `g`, that would be more, but still with that last caveat (`[^.]` instead of `[!.]` with some shells):

```
mv public_html/*.[!.][!.][fg] public_html/images/
```

For 3 *letters*:

```
mv public_html/*.[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]][fg] public_html/images/
```

For with jpg, png or gif, with the `zsh` shell:

```
mv public_html/*.(jpg|gif|png) public_html/images/
```

Or with ksh or `zsh -o kshglob` or `bash -O extglob`:

```
mv public_html/*.@(jpg|gif|png) public_html/images/
```

Comment: "`g`, `,` (comma) or `g`" should be "`g`, `,` (comma) or `f`", no?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `bash` or friends, you can use

```
mv public_html/*.??[gf] public_html/images/
```

or, to be more exact with matching

```
mv public_html/*.{jpg,png,gif} public_html/images/
```